# Custom List button not working as expected

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, custom-button, related-list, urlhacking

I have a two custom object Sample and Sample detail. Sample detail has a lookup relationship to the Sample record. And both the records have lookup relationship to the Case. Below is the Sample record which currently has an association to Case.

[image]

When I create a Sample Detail record from the related list. I need to pull case that is in the Sample to the Sample Details automatically, so I created a custom URL List button

```
/lightning/o/Sample_Detail__c/new?defaultFieldValues=Sample__c={!Sample__c.Id},Case__c={!Sample__c.Case__c}
```

added this button the related list.

[image]

when I use this button

[image]

It populates the Sample ID but removes the Case field from create new page

[image]

What is that I am missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated

Updated to below URL still case value isnt getting autopopulated from the parent

```
/lightning/o/Sample_Detail__c/new?defaultFieldValues=Sample__c%3D{!Sample__c.Id},Case%3D{!Sample__c.Case__c}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=` is a reserved character for URLs, so you must encode them as %3D:

```
defaultFieldValues=Sample__c%3D{!Sample__c.Id},Case__c%3D{!Sample__c.Case__c}
```

Note that the `{!` and `}` are *not* encoded, because they will be replaced with the literal Id value when rendered.

Comment: Thank you, now I can see the field up but dont see the Case ID populated from the Parent.. Added the screenshot in the question

Comment: @user4912134 That was a typo on my part. Don't forget the __c. I'll edit.

Comment: No still it doesnt work.. I added the __c it removes the field from create new page

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can I pass the associated CaseId as the parameter.. I am kind of stuck, any help is really appreciated

Comment: Can you please suggest me what I might be missing that the case ID cannot be passed